# How to create GIT project on self-hosted Team Foundation Server 2012

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012, tfs

Can anybody tell me how I can create a GIT project on a self-hosted Team Foundation Server 2012? I know it's possible on Microsofts hosted TFS.

I have updated the self-hosted TFS to Update 2 (and have updated my own VS2012 to Update 2 too).

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported on `on-premise` TFS 2012 servers. The last thing I read (which I'm struggling to find now), suggested it would be around 12 months before it was made available to on-premise solutions.